# Create New Field in Dataframe Using Complex Conditional Summing Logic

Tags: python, if-statement, sum, conditional-statements, pandas-groupby

Below is my table (Python dataframe).  I'm trying to create the last column in purple text.

[image]

Below is the logic I want to implement:

1. For each unique 'cbsa' value, if the associated 'zip' field values are all the same then set 'age_HC01_EST_VC31_2' field equal to 'age_HC01_EST_VC31' field (see rows highlighted in yellow).
2. For each unique 'cbsa' value, if the associated 'zip' field values are different then set 'age_HC01_EST_VC31_2' field equal to the sum of 'age_HC01_EST_VC31' field values (see rows highlighted in orange).
3. For each unique 'cbsa' value, if the associated 'zip' field values are some the same and some different, then set 'age_HC01_EST_VC31_2' field equal to the sum of UNIQUE 'age_HC01_EST_VC31' field values (see rows highlighted in blue).

I have tried using groupby and then sum on 'cbsa' field ... but it doesn't work for the specific, multi-layered logic I'm trying to implement.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['new_column']="" #Initialise and empty column

#iterate through all unique values
for item in df['cbsa'].unique():
    if len(df['zip'].loc[df['cbsa']==item].unique())==1:
        df['new_column'].loc[df['cbsa']==item] = df['age_HC01_EST_VC31'].loc[df['cbsa']==item]
    else:
        df['new_column'].loc[df['cbsa']==item] = sum(df['age_HC01_EST_VC31'].loc[df['cbsa']==item].unique())
```

Comment: There might be some other easy way. But this also works

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, your logic can be summarized as following: for each unique 'cbsa' value, set 'age_HC01_EST_VC31_2' field equal to the sum of UNIQUE 'age_HC01_EST_VC31' field values.

If that is correct, here is a way to do it: first group by `cbsa`, find the unique `age_HC01_EST_VC31` values and sum these values.

```
import pandas as pd
dic = {'zip': [57401, 57401, 57401, 57401, 98520, 98550, 79604, 79602, 79602, 79601],
       'age_HC01_EST_VC31': [15.5, 15.5, 15.5, 15.5, 13.5, 17.3, 14.9, 18, 18, 11],
       'cbsa': [10100, 10100, 10100, 10100, 10140, 10140, 10180, 10180, 10180, 10180]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
df.join(df.groupby('cbsa').age_HC01_EST_VC31.unique().apply(sum), on='cbsa', rsuffix='_2')

#    age_HC01_EST_VC31   cbsa    zip  age_HC01_EST_VC31_2
# 0               15.5  10100  57401                 15.5
# 1               15.5  10100  57401                 15.5
# 2               15.5  10100  57401                 15.5
# 3               15.5  10100  57401                 15.5
# 4               13.5  10140  98520                 30.8
# 5               17.3  10140  98550                 30.8
# 6               14.9  10180  79604                 43.9
# 7               18.0  10180  79602                 43.9
# 8               18.0  10180  79602                 43.9
# 9               11.0  10180  79601                 43.9
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a long way, but gets the work done (you need to rename the age columns - I just called it age1).

```
grouped = df.groupby(['cbsa','zip'])[['age1']].mean().reset_index()
summed = grouped.groupby(['cbsa'])[['age1']].sum().reset_index()
df = pd.merge(df, summed, how='left', on='cbsa')
```